# Flutter/Firebase Google login not working after building apk file

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have made android app that uses firebase and google_sign. Then I have release apk by flutter build apk. But after installing that apk file locally in my phone the google login page does't works although I works perfectly.

I am aware that when publishing the app to playstore we need to add provided SHA1 key but if I am not planing to release to google play then is there any way to make with work?

Comment: for google sign in you need to add sha1 to your gcp console and fill in the consent screen for you to be able to login using google

Comment: aslo debug and see if it throws error 12500

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a late answer, but the debug and even the prod signing key that you use on your local machine to create the APK won't work if you use AppBundle or Google App Signing (which is the norm now unless you opt out).

For **Production** apps go to Google Play Console. Click your app, click Release Management -> App Signing. Then look under **App signing certificate** here you can copy the SHA1 to your firebase console under Project Settings -> SHA certificate fingerprints.

This is because your upload key is swapped out on the google servers when you upload your APK / AppBundle. Meaning that your production app served to users from the play store has a different SHA1 fingerprint than anything on your local machine (including your signing keys) thats why they dont work when going live but work while debugging locally.

Comment: yup - this helped me.  i didn't see this documented elsewhere - thanks  :)

Comment: do we need to update googleservice.json after adding that

Comment: @AsbahRiyas no it worked by only copying SHA-1 key to firebase, we don't need to rebuild apk or change google-services.json

Comment: This solves a lot of problems for me! Thanks! Also didn't find this hint in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

In your console use the command after entering android folder using

```
cd android

gradlew signinReport
```

This command generates certificates and SHA keys which you need. When we first create Firebase, we give the SHA debug key which no longer works in production version.

Go to the project settings in Firebase console and change the SHA field with the release key generated using the above command.

Keep in mind, this command generates a bunch of keys including debug and release keys. You need the release one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but check if you add `SHA1` for release to Firebase you can following the next steps:

1. open the `gradlew` file in terminal
2. in terminal add `gradlew signingReport` you shoud find `SHA1` to release
3. open your project in firebase and setting project
4. under the SHA certificate fingerprints add your `key`