# Flutter doesnt work properly with firebase on release apk/bundle

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, apk, release

When I execute `flutter run` my app works fine with Firebase (cloud_firestore) but whenever I do one of these commands:
`flutter build apk --release`
or
`flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64`
my app does not work properly with cloud_firestore. It doesn't do CRUD operations.

pubspec.yaml (plugins):

```
  google_sign_in: 4.5.1
  firebase_auth: 0.16.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
```

app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '15'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '15.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tomeruby.iusefully"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        // ndk {
        //     abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        // }
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you need more information, please let me know.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840495/flutter-firebase-google-login-not-working-after-building-apk-file

Comment: It's not login related, I'll update if it helps.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I do not get a log tho...

Comment: Have you added the release Keystore SHA1 to your project in the firebase console?

Comment: yes, i haver 3 fingerprints 2 sha1s 1 debug 1 release and another one sha25 (or smth) for release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

in your project gradle.build to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

and in
gradle.properties add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Why downgrading google services would help?

Comment: may last version not compatible for now u can upgrade to v7