# Firebase phone auth not initiating OTP only in release mode but works on Debug mode even after added sha1 for release mode

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, sha1

Steps how I implemented.

As advised, I implemented all the way. It was quite good in debug mode. Unfortunately its not working in release mode even I added my debug and release sha1 keys in firebase console.

Step 1.   Coding part is here

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
    (PhoneAuthCredential user) {
  successMessage('Your phone number verified successfully!');
  _loginNotifier.validate();
};

 final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (FirebaseAuthException authException) {
  errorMessage('Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}');
  print(
      'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}');
};

 final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
    (String verificationId) {
  this._verificationId = verificationId;
  print("time out");
};

 firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: '+$_phoneWithCC',
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

Step 2:
[image: Here is the firebase console sha1 keys for debug and release mode]

Added all three different sha1 keys but still not working:(

**Error I am getting:**

As I said, in debug mode all good as expected
But in release mode, after initiating the otp function, immediately PhineVerificationFailed with null message and null code.

If still anything I missed please advice. Thanks all

Comment: so can you try downloading the new google-services.json after you added the sha1 and replace it with the old one.

Comment: Yes @KrishBhanushali I did.. so wired :(

Comment: in release mode, immediately i am getting called verificationFailed function.
my bad, the data from verificationFailed function is null :(

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore PATH_JKS_FILE -alias XXX 

this is how I got my release SHA1 key -FYI

Comment: Hi, when you say 'release' are you releasing to the play store (and using google app signing)? If so you need to use the play store sha fingerprint (not your local machines one you build with): See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840495/flutter-firebase-google-login-not-working-after-building-apk-file/59743742#59743742

Comment: Yes, you can see in the image, i added playstore sha1 too
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ZCP.png

Comment: @MuthuS Have you added permissions in your manifest file for internet ? That solved my issues in release mode.

Comment: Yes, i did.. Since all other API's are working..

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36999751/4729203

Answer (score 6):

Apart from `SHA1` - you also need `SHA256` thumbprint for release apk.

I faced similar issue for firebase google authentication.

Can you add `SHA256` thumbprint to firebase project console and try again ?

Comment: ok lemme try, between, why the failed message and code is null? did my implementation is correct?

Comment: https://ibb.co/rvZPgtK after added sha-256 release and debug keys then downloaded the json file and rebuild the app then i am getting the same error:(

Comment: between, how to get SHA1 for release mode.. keytool -list -v -keystore PATH_JKS_FILE -alias XXX is this correct?? @abijith

Comment: open cmd inside your android folder, then run the following command - 
./gradlew signingReport

link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding `sha256` and `SHA1`, you need to add your email in the  `Firebase` console. See the attached image.

[image]

Comment: OMG, this saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Glad that it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

After adding SHA1 you have to reinstall your app from Google Play.

Comment: i have't release also. i am trying install release apk directly. not from play store. FYI @Mr Random

Answer (score 0):

For my case I was just missing the 'Andoid Device Verification' API for my Firebase project from Google Cloud.

[https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project={put_your_project_name_here}](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=%7Bput_your_project_name_here%7D)